# How does `variables` work in `graphql-subscriptions` withFilter function?

Tags: node.js, graphql, graphql-subscriptions

I create a nodejs graphql application using `graphql-subscriptions` library to handle pubsub. Below is the source code:

```
import { withFilter } from 'graphql-subscriptions';

const SOMETHING_CHANGED_TOPIC = 'something_changed';

export const resolvers = {
  Subscription: {
    somethingChanged: {
      subscribe: withFilter(() => pubsub.asyncIterator(SOMETHING_CHANGED_TOPIC), (payload, variables) => {
        return payload.somethingChanged.id === variables.relevantId;
      }),
    },
  },
}
```

As you can see that there is a `variables` parameter in the second parameter of `withFilter` function. I found that this `variables` is the same the client sub request. Is this what `variables` mean? How can I understand the purpose of `variables`? Or can I set up different values for this `variables`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use **withFilter()** if the subscription data will publish to particular user based on the variable(subscription input) and payload(return data) conditions.